# Is there a limit to how many spells you can add to your spellbook per day?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard

Basically I was able to purchase seven scrolls of lower level spells (two first, three second, two third) that would be useful to my wizard. Assuming an hour per spell, could I scribe them in all in a day? Or is there a restriction of one a day?

I remember something about there being a daily restriction but I can’t find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two processes to copying a spell scroll into a spellbook: studying the scroll, and scribing the spell.

Studying the scroll always takes 1 hour, regardless of the spell. It requires a DC 15 + spell level Spellcraft check. And in the case of studying a scroll (rather than another spellbook), it destroys the scroll.

After you have successfully studied it, you must scribe it. This takes an hour *per spell level*, so a 1st-level spell is another hour on top of the hour spent studying, while a 2nd-level spell would be two additional hours or a 3rd-level spell would be three additional hours. It also takes up a page per spell level, and costs some gold depending on the spell level (specifically, \$Lv_\text{spell}^2 \times 10\text{ gp}\$ for spells 1st-level or higher; 5 gp for cantrips).

Nowhere, however, is an explicit limit on how much time per day you can spend on studying and scribing spells. It takes (considerably) longer than you indicated, 21 hours, but you can keep doing it, at least until your GM starts indicating that fatigue is causing problems (as with all things related to lack of rest, exactly when and how that works is left up to the GM).

Comment: Studying a scroll doesn't obliterate the scroll; copying it does: "a spell successfully copied from a magic scroll disappears from the parchment."

Comment: Covers both requirements for scribing spells into spellbook as well as bodily limitations before exhaustion.

Comment: Ah. One hour per spell level. I knew I had missed something! Thanks for the catch.